laravel dynamic route prefix throwing error when route:cache is called
Route::prefix('{prefix}')->whereIn('prefix' ,['prefix1','prefix2']) ...
this prefix is dynamic and we just validate it from the whereIn
now the problem is when we run php artisan route:cache
it throws an error that says :

InvalidArgumentException
Routing requirement for "prefix" cannot be empty.

how to fix w/o having a static prefix?
thanks
tried setting up default prefix on the middleware but still, it works on browser but not when creating route cache

I don't have any problems with this, try adding / to the dynamic prefix: '/{prefix}'
